# create specific validation symfony 4 or regex

Tags: symfony, validation, input, symfony4

I work with symfony4.
I would add same validation to my input number to accept only values like :

```
1
10
100
1000
10000
100000
1000000
```

Comment: Regex: `10{0,6}`

Answer (score 1):

You have to use Choice validation. All info about choice validation You can find [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Choice.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex with this pattern

> "/^1+0*/"

Example

```
class MyClass
{
    /**
     * @Assert\Regex(
     *     pattern     = "/^1+0*/",
     *     message="Wrong number"
     * )
     */
    protected $myNumber;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex with this pattern

```
"/^1[0]*$/"
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/eSnOfp/1

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by this pattern :

```
pattern="[0-1]+"
```